# Jenkins can not locate JAVA_HOME on MacOS

Tags: java, macos, jenkins

I have installed jenkins on my local machine. When I try to run a JOB i am getting an error

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/libexec/java_home
I have multiple java version installed and properly configured JAVA_HOME-> /usr/libexec/java_home

In terminal **java -version** returns ->
java version "17.0.8" 2023-07-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.8+9-LTS-211)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.8+9-LTS-211, mixed mode, sharing)

**whereis JAVA_HOME** returns ->
JAVA_HOME: /usr/libexec/JAVA_HOME

terminal command **/usr/libexec/java_home -V**  return ->
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
17.0.8 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 17.0.8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home
15.0.1 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 15.0.1" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: Switch to the Jenkins user and try running the same commands to see if this user also has access to the JAVA_HOME